# KVM does not boot with .iso disk images. Device or resource busy?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I've been trying to set up a windows VM on my Ubuntu box by following the linked blog post
http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/

So I have done everything step-by-step, only changing system specific things, and i end up getting the following error message after starting the VM:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: VFIO 0000:01:00.0 BAR 0 mmap unsupported. Performance may be slow
qemu-system-x86_64: vfio_bar_write(,0x0, 0x0, 4) failed: Device or resource busy
```

I use an AMD CPU instead of an Intel one, I have also ran VMs previously on it, the iommu module is enabled in the bios.

After loading the required modules, I was looking for the hardware piece i want to disable by the system (my second GPU), so I ran the `lscpi -nn | grep ATI` command - to get the  returned the following:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cypress PRO [Radeon HD 5850] [1002:6899]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cypress HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5800 Series] [1002:aa50]
```

From this I assume only the VGA controller is required.

So I added the ID of the device to the ignore list (which is located at /etc/initramfs-tools/modules), like `pci_stub ids=1002:6899`. To complete the action, i ran `update-initramfs -u` as root, restarted the system, and after the restart of the system the left screen went dark. I assume, that this works as its supposed to do.

After this, I created a vfio-pci conf file, where I would store the device's PCI address, just as in the tutorial.

Well, and then the boot script, where I edited only some system specific settings.

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -M q35 -m 4096 -cpu host \
-smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 \ 
-bios /usr/share/qemu/bios.bin -vga none \
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1 \
-drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Win7.img,id=disk,format=raw -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=disk \
-boot menu=on
```

I read through the post several times without noticing anything, I'm not sure if its that I missed something.

### Edit 1; ISO images drive the KVM device crazy

After trying several settings, I noticed that whenever I tried to start the qemu vm with a virtual optical drive, it crashed. Without any drives it started without any problems.

### MUHAHAHAAA! It works! (But i still dont know why)

Well, I solved the problem (sort of). I don't get those nasty messages anymore and that's because I swapped the two graphics cards. Turns out: the kvm, vfio or at least one of the components of the VM do not like, if the VM's gpu is located in the first PCIe slot.

Comment: @AndréDaniel - We have customers using GPU passthrough to provide virtual desktops to users doing CAD/graphics work. There are business reasons for it - although I wouldn't use KVM for it.

Comment: @Rex consider using Nvidia Quadro cards, their BIOS and (Windows) drivers are apparently designed for passthrough and are less likely to break. But still, it it works for you then great, but don't expect that to last long as any update of either the kernel, QEMU or Windows driver may break it.

Comment: @AndréDaniel - this is not my question. Simply responding to your comment. Also, the quadro cards are nice, but the newer K1/K2 cards are much nicer in a virtual environment for vGPU sharing :)

Comment: @Rex thanks, good to know (and sorry for the confusion, didn't pay attention to the usernames). :)

Comment: @Max - thanks a lot for this post; we had exactly the same issue with two Radeon HD 4000 series. Removing the iso image made it work for us. We didn't get lucky with reverting the graphics cards, but we resolved to just installing the Windows in the VM w/o passthrough, and then using that image when starting kvm with pass through.